# Can an Excel file that was edited and saved in a WinZip file be recovered?

Tags: microsoft-excel, winzip

I have a Zip file that contains four Excel files. I have edited those Excel files without extracting them, and closed them properly after being saved.

But when I reopened those files without extracting, I didn't find the changes I have made.

Is there any way I can recover the data?

Answer (score 1):

You did not edit the original file.  When you opened the file from inside the Zip file, it created a temporary Excel file.  That is the file you edited and saved.  Since you did *save* it, it exists somewhere.  Try looking for the file on your desktop, or in the same folder where the .ZIP file is.  It might have a random name, but would have a .XLS or .XLSX suffix.  Worst case, you can search your entire drive for .XLS and sort by date, it would be the one with the latest creation date.

Comment: If you have Everything software by voidtools.com installed . You can search filter by documents and sort by modified. Try the most recent. It can Acess all files even in temp folder that is where files are saved when extracted.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Keltari's answer, if you open the file from inside the ZIP archive again and choose "Save As" you will probably be able to look at the location and see where the previous files were saved.

Answer (score 1):

i did the same and found it here (change the user name, mine is thompsonm)  : C:\Users\thompsonm\AppData\Local\Temp\